# External hard-disk cannot safely remove

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, eject

My external hard drive cannot be remove in my laptop. Usually, it have 'safely remove this device', but mine doesn't have one and cannot be eject. It is because of the virus? I already install Unlock er apps but nothing happened? I personally don't want to format it because i have a lot work in my HDD. What should i do?

Comment: you can always shut down your laptop and then unplug the disk safely. how is the disk connected to your laptop, and how do you mount it when it gets plugged in?

Answer (score 2):

Try using Disk Management. Here are the steps (Windows 7 only):

1. Click on Start Menu.
2. Type mmc and select mmc. Give administrator prompt. Console root window appears.
3. Go to File > diskmgmt.
4. If your disk is mounted, it should appear here. Right click on the box which says Disk1 or Disk2 or Disk3 or something like that.
5. Click on Offline. Then just pull the plug out.

If Windows 8 or 8.1 : http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/disk-management-windows-8.htm and follow the steps 4-5.

If Windows 10 : http://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/7-ways-to-open-disk-management-in-windows-10.html and follow the stes 4-5.

If Windows Vista : http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windowsvista/ht/disk-management-vista.htm and follow the steps 4-5.

If Windows XP : http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windowsxp/ht/disk-management-xp.htm and follow steps the steps 4-5 (I recommend a upgrade).

If Windows 98 : Sorry, couldn't find a web page. (You should DEFINITELY upgrade).

Comment: Look, you didn't specify your OS so I took everything into account.

Comment: I seriously believe (and hope) that you are using a Windows OS because you said 'safely remove this device' and it really sounds like a windows thing.

Comment: Yes, its windows 8 os